# Cannot delete/move files with special characters in file name

Tags: files, filesystem, encoding, filename

As you can see below the files have uncommon characters.

[image: file manager screenshot]

Deleting them either in the terminal or Dolphin returns the error:

> No such file or directory

Running `ls -la` on the directory gave me this output:

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 aalap aalap      0 Nov 14 01:05 ??
-rw-rw-r--  1 aalap aalap      0 Nov 14 01:05 ?2?.???љ?!?Gb??σ?[?F?
-rw-rw-r--  1 aalap aalap      0 Nov 14 01:05 ??3]d???:????????1????G?p?ȋ??????嫳?d????ą-??
-rw-rw-r--  1 aalap aalap      0 Nov 14 01:05 3l??#g?w????O?JKB7?co??քH??bT?NA???S???X?I?A?qC??M?I???
-rw-rw-r--  1 aalap aalap      0 Nov 14 01:05 ??8??-?@,?Zp?[?bI????7^?ñ[?ڏ??z?O???ч??eEȰ?+??,OF??h
```

I ran an `fsck` command on the partition from another OS but it didn't change anything.

How do I remove these files?

Comment: Did you set up your system to have an encrypted home directory?

Comment: @dobey I did not.

Comment: Corrupt file system

Comment: @Panther So how do I fix it?

Comment: Fsck from a live cd

Comment: @Panther You are mistaken.  This is _not_, by itself, an indication of a corrupt file system, and even if it _was_ caused by data corruption of some kind, fsck won't do anything about it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I enter a file or directory name containing spaces or special characters in the terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/984801/how-do-i-enter-a-file-or-directory-name-containing-spaces-or-special-characters)

Comment: I've had files with unrecognized charaters in the name. Renaming the files worked. then they could be deleted.

Comment: A more likely explanation is a bug in the program that created these files: for some reason `char* namefile` ended up pointing to the wrong address.

Comment: What's your locale?  Are you sure that it matches the locale of your filenames?

Comment: @ravery I haven't tried that solution yet!

Comment: @FedericoPoloni This happened right after a system crashed. It happened over a month ago so I'm not sure what the exact reason was anymore. Shouldn't have procrastinated so much, come to think of it. -_-

Answer (score 37, accepted):

A simple way would be to remove these files by their inode. :)

Use `ls -li` in the directory with the uncommon characters to show the inode number of each file, e.g.,

```
$ ls -li
total 0
133370 -rw-r--r-- 1 malte malte 0 Dec 30 19:00 ?2?.???љ?!?Gb??σ?[?F?
132584 -rw-r--r-- 1 malte malte 0 Dec 30 18:59 ??3]d???:????????1????G?p?ȋ??????嫳?d????ą-??
```

Next, use the `find` utility to delete the corresponding file by its name, using the syntax `find <somepath> -inum <inode_number> -exec rm -i {} \;`, as in the following example:

```
$ find . -inum 133370 -exec rm -i {} \;
rm: remove regular empty file ‘./?2?.???љ?!?Gb??σ?[?F?’? y
$ ls -li
total 0
132584 -rw-r--r-- 1 malte malte 0 Dec 30 18:59 ??3]d???:????????1????G?p?ȋ??????嫳?d????ą-??
```

The `-i` option to `rm` is not really necessary, I just added it to keep you from accidentally removing files you didn't mean to remove. :) It causes `rm` to ask for confirmation for each file that you want to delete.

If you want to remove multiple files by their inodes, you can use the `-o` (meaning *or*) syntax for `find`:

```
$ find .  \( -inum 133370 -o -inum 132584 \) -exec rm -i {} \;
rm: remove regular empty file ‘./?2?.???љ?!?Gb??σ?[?F?’? y
rm: remove regular empty file ‘./??3]d???:????????1????G?p?ȋ??????嫳?d????ą-??’? y
```

You can add more inode numbers by extending the expression in parentheses with more `-o -inum <inode_number>` expressions.

Comment: How about `rm -ri .`?

Comment: This worked: find <somepath> -inum <inode_number> -exec rm -i {} \;

What does '-inum', '{}', and '\' do in the command?

Comment: How do I remove multiple files at one go? Also, thank you, you made my day!

Comment: @BrentBaccala `rm -ri .` is not deleting files by inode, though. It will simply recurse through the entire working directory and ask for each file if you want to remove it - and you have to be very attentive which files it is asking for so as not to accidentally remove unwanted ones. I certainly would not want to use this command for my home directory - it contains LOTS of files. ;)

Comment: @karjedavpalaa (1) `-inum` tells `find` to look for files by their inode number. (2) `{}` matches the file(s) found by `grep`. (3) \ escapes the `;` symbol which terminates the command passed to the `-exec` option of `find`. (4) I have edited my answer to explain how to remove multiple files in one go.

Answer (score 13):

It is important to understand that this is *not* the kind of "filesystem corruption" that `fsck` will help with.  As far as the filesystem is concerned, file names can be *any sequence of bytes*, as long as no single byte has the value 0x00 (ASCII NUL, C end-of-string marker) or 0x2F (`/`, the directory separator).  (If a file name does somehow get a 00 or 2F byte embedded within it, `fsck` should fix that.)

Rather, what you have is file names that application software (Dolphin, `ls`) think contain characters that are *un-displayable* in your "locale", so it is replacing them with placeholder characters.  You can't *type* those characters either, so manipulating the files is harder, but you can do it as long as you do it without ever typing or copying and pasting the name.  For instance, if you delete or rename the problem files directly from within Dolphin, that should Just Work (I would go so far as to say that if it doesn't work, that's a bug in Dolphin).

If you need to do something about them from the shell (for instance, if they are owned by `root` and therefore cannot be modified by a GUI program), you can name them indirectly using "glob" patterns, which will be expanded to the correct sequence(s) of bytes and passed along.

Now, of course, you wouldn't want to delete stuff by accident because your glob pattern matched too much, so my recommendation would be to use the Perl `rename` utility to convert each filename to its hex encoding:

```
$ rename '$_ = unpack("H*", $_)' *
```

This doesn't destroy any information - neither the file itself, nor whatever meaning might originally have been encoded in the filename before it got mangled.  It can be undone for specific files with e.g.

```
$ rename '$_ = pack("H*", $_)' 696d706f7274616e742e646f63
```

Caution: there are two programs named `rename`, from different origins; the above commands will only work with the one originating with Perl.  In Ubuntu, the one you want is the one from the "rename" package, not the one from the "util-linux" package.  `rename -h` will distinguish: this is what you want...

```
$ rename -h
Usage:
    rename [ -h|-m|-V ] [ -v ] [ -n ] [ -f ] [ -e|-E perlexpr]*|perlexpr
    [ files ]
# ...
```

... this is not what you want ...

```
$ rename -h

Usage:
 rename [options] <expression> <replacement> <file>...
# ...
```

The key thing to look for is "perlexpr".  You might have an older version of the Perl rename that doesn't understand all of the options above, but the command I showed should still work.

Edit: Under 14.04 .5 the perl script that's included for `rename` does not support the -h switch. You can confirm you have the correct one by checking it's man page with `man rename` in which case the top line will contain:

> RENAME(1)                                       Perl Programmers Reference Guide                                       RENAME(1)

Comment: rename --version
Unknown option: version

Comment: @ElderGeek What does `file $(which rename)` print?  (Make sure you have the `file` package installed, first.)

Comment: `/usr/bin/rename: symbolic link to /etc/alternatives/rename` (`file` is installed by default) Actually you have to chase down the symbolic links to get `/usr/bin/file-rename: a /usr/bin/perl -w script, ASCII text executable
` but `man rename` is a quicker indication...

Comment: @ElderGeek If it's a perl script, then it's probably an older version of the "one originating with Perl", that doesn't support `--version`; the command I suggested should still work. (/usr/share/doc/rename/changelog.gz on my computer, which runs Debian unstable, indicates that `--version` was added in version 0.10 of the Perl rename, in 2013.  I'm surprised Ubuntu is still shipping something older than that, but this program hasn't actually changed its _functionality_ since 2007(!) so it's fine.)

Comment: Ah! That explains the confusion. Despite many claims to the contrary, Debian is not Ubuntu. I can't speak for every release, but some currently supported versions of Ubuntu  LTS (14.04) still doesn't have that. (Although 16.04 does)

Comment: @ElderGeek Comparing https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rename to https://packages.qa.debian.org/r/rename.html , all supported releases of both Ubuntu and Debian ship the same upstream version of the `rename` package.  So I don't understand how yours manages to be older...

Comment: Oh for heavens' sake, Launchpad doesn't show LTS versions? ... *wanders off grumbling about the [cascade of attention-deficit teenagers](https://www.jwz.org/doc/cadt.html)* ...

Comment: @ElderGeek anyway I revised the advice to talk about `rename -h` and I'd appreciate it if you could check whether that works with your older version. `-h` isn't mentioned at all in the upstream changelog, so I _hope_ it existed since eight o'clock, Day One, but you never know™.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71535/discussion-between-elder-geek-and-zwol).

Comment: @ElderGeek Chat is a misfeature. I will not discuss my answers anywhere other than the comment threads on those answers.

Comment: Suit yourself. IMHO closing down avenues of communication is seldom an effective approach.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend Midnight Commander - a terminal based file manager. It's the first and probably most  useful software tool I install on any system.

It will allow you to select the files using point & click (if you have console mouse functionality enabled via gpm) or using the cursor & Ins keys.

Having selected the files press F8 to delete them

Theres no need to type file names or rename files but you may need to run Midnight Commander as sudo.